# Jcarousel how to set start point

Tags: jquery

I am currenty using Jcarousel with a light box plugin. I have some thumbnails and when each one is clicked a light box pops up with the larger version of thumbnail in it, also i have in that light box the ability to click left or right to rotate throught the other thumbnails(this is all generated using the Jcarousel) My issue is i would like the carousel to start the corresponding thumb nail that was clicked to open the light box:

HTML:

```
<div id="productAlts">
    <div class="altWrap">
        <a id="close_x" class="close" href="#" title="close quick view" ></a>
        <ul>
        <% int altImageCount = 0;
           foreach (var img in addtImages)
           {
               altImageCount++;
           }
        %>
        <% int i = 0;
           foreach (var img in addtImages)
           {
               i++;
               if (i != altImageCount)
               {%>
                  <li class="<%=img %>">
                  <img src="http://www.someurl.com/images/products/<%=img.Replace(".jpg", "") %>l.jpg"  alt="<%= Model.Name %>" title="<%= Model.Name %>" width="500" height="500" />
                  </li>
              <% }
           } %>
       </ul>
   </div>
```

jquery:

```
    function QuickAlternate() {
$('.alternateImages ul li').click(function (e) {
    $('#productAlts').lightbox_me({
        centered: true,
        onLoad: function () {
$('#productAlts ul').jcarousel({
    wrap: 'circular', scroll: 1, visible: 1
});
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

}

If anyone can help it would be very appreciated since i have been banging my head against this for a while

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I understand what you're looking for, but it sounds like the `start` option as shown in http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Configuration should do what you want? So something like this:

```
$('#productAlts ul').jcarousel({
    wrap: 'circular', scroll: 1, visible: 1, start: 4
});
```

would start on the 4th one?

Comment: start position is what i want but I was wanting to scroll to a the specific thumbnail image that is clicked on to open the the light box that contains the carousel

Comment: Ah, let me clarify: you create jcarousel with images 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, and start is set to 4. You slide the carousel to image 5, and click: a lightbox appears with image 5. You then move forward to image 2, and close the lightbox. You then want the carousel to be showing image 2. Is this what you mean?

Comment: mainly i have 3 thumbnails, you click one and a light box comes up with tht exact thumbnail you clicked but larger, you then have the options with the jcarousel to cycle through the images. Now say they dont click the first thumbnail , they click the 2nd or third I would like the light box when it pops up to have the carousel go to the appropriate matching image

Comment: Ah. You, my friend, are unfortunately going to have to do that heavy lifting yourself as the standard jCarousel library does not appear to have the lightbox integration nor does it provide a convenient way to change the currently visible item. You will have to write some custom javascript that ties into the lightbox's code (this would depend on your lightbox implementation: I use jQuery Colorbox) and into jCarousel and updates the carousel when the lightbox changes. Good luck.